# How do I select a class with Inner html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, class

So I have two divs:

```
<div class="someGenericClass">1 Item</div>
<div class="someGenericClass">Another Item</div>
```

If I am given two variables:

```
classVariable = ".someGenericClass";
innerHTMLVariable = "Another Item";
```

How can I select the second div element based on class, and then the innerHTML if I have no say in adding an ID to that section. Using either javascript or jQuery. I know this isn't optimal to search by innerHTML, but I don't have a say in adding ID's and so on with what I'm doing, and I can't rely on the divs being in a set order.

```
$(classVariable).somehowInnerHTML?
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
$(".someGenericClass:contains('Another Item')" ).<any action you want to do in this element>
```

To get the object in a variable:

```
var variable = $(".someGenericClass:contains('Another Item')" );
```

Answer (score 3):

Well you already know that this is not very reliable to search by element innerHTML content, so.. I will give you some hints of how you can do it.

**1).** With pure Javascript I would use filter method of Array:

```
var classVariable = ".someGenericClass";
var innerHTMLVariable = "Another Item";

var found = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(classVariable)).filter(function(div) {
    return div.innerHTML === innerHTMLVariable;
});
```

This code will find all the divs with innerHTML content equal to `innerHTMLVariable`.

**2).** With jQuery:

```
$(classVariable + ':contains(' + innerHTMLVariable + ')');
```

Above code is not equivalent to pure js version, because it uses `:contains` selector, so it matches divs which have text content, but of course it will also match `<div class="someGenericClass">Some text Another Item content</div>`.

jQuery equivalent would be

```
$(classVariable).filter(function() {
    return $(this).text() === innerHTMLVariable;
});
```